# Using tfl data api - tutorial?

Tags: api, proxy, transport, consumption

I have developed apps for 3 years and am now looking to build an app that uses TFL (transport for london) api calls.  I was reading their guidelines and read the following:

> "Distribution
>   Developers consuming TfL data and providing public services built on it are expected 
>   to provide the hosting capacity necessary to serve those public consumers. You 
>   should take our data and proxy it, you shouldn’t allow all your clients to hit our service 
>   driectly. This is intended to reduce TfL’s cost liability for hosting and content delivery."

While I have done a lot of app development, I have never hosted my own proxy receiving responses from an api.  I have searched the internet for tutorials on this (ideally specific to TFL, but general ones would be awesome too), but can't find any that help.

Does anyone know of any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spoke to TFL about the Bus Times and it turns out you don't need to run this data via a database and can instead have users making direct calls to the API via your iPhone app.  Great news :-)